# Flutter beta hot reload in VSCode works for web but not iOS and Android (which works in Android studio)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, hot-reload

I'm running Mac Catalina and have both Android Studio and VSCode installed

```
❯ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.3.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

I have a very simple app

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: Text("Hello World!"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

If I run the app from Android Studio then hot reload works just fine, e.g. changing the text and saving will update the text on any of the devices (iOS, Android or Chrome).

But if I do the same in VSCode, i.e. F5 (`Debug: Start debugging`), then hot reload only works for web. Looking in the debug console I see the following each time I make a change and save.

```
Reloaded 1 of 502 libraries in 167ms.
```

But no updates on the screen (except when running Chrome where output in the debug console looks the same as with the others.). I find this very odd!

#### Update

I've opened a [bug report](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2632) at `dart-code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my. I forgot to put the app inside a stateless app. My mistake!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: Text("Hello World!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```